# How to exclude a large set of of ids from elasticsearch result?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr, lucene, elastic-stack, recommendation-engine

I have a lot of *Products* indexed in elasticsearch. I need to exclude a list of ids (that I am fetching from a SQL database), from a query in elasticsearch. 
Suppose *Products* are stored as,

```
{
  "id" : "1",
  "name" : "shirt",
  "size" : "xl"
}
```

We show a list of recommended products to a customer based on some algorithm using elasticsearch. 
**If a customer marks a product as 'Not Interested', we don't have to show him that product again.** 
We keep such products in a separate SQL table with *product_id*, *customer_id* and *status* 'not_interested'.

Now while fetching recommendations for a customer on runtime, we get the list  of 'not_interested' products from the SQL database, and send the array of *product_ids* in a not filter in elasticsearch to exclude them from recommendation.
But the problem arises, when the size of *product_ids* array becomes too large.

How should I store the product_id and customer_id mapping in elasticsearch 
to filter out the 'not_interested' products on runtime using elasticsearch only?

Will it make sense to store them as nested objects or parent/child documents.? Or some completely other way to store such that I can exclude some ids from the result efficiently.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can exclude IDs (or any other literal strings) efficiently using a `terms query`.

Both Elasticsearch and Solr have this. It is very powerful and very efficient.

Elasticsearch has this with the `IDS query`. This query is in fact a terms query on the _uid field. Make sure you use this query in a `mustNot` clause within a `bool` query. See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html

In Solr you can use the `terms query` within a `fq` like `fq=-{!terms f=id}doc334,doc125,doc777,doc321,doc253`. Note the minus to indicate that it is a negation. See: http://yonik.com/solr-terms-query/

Comment: Will this not be a problem if the list of ids to be negated is a huge list. Let's say tens of thousand of such doc ids.

Comment: Not a problem if you do this server-side because this query is optimized for your use-case. I have done this for tens of thousands and it was still very fast! To see when it becomes slow you have to test this as this depends on your index size, but this will be a very high number.

Comment: @drjz The implementation in elasticsearch is well documented here https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html. Can I have something similar to this in Solr as well. _fq=-{!terms f=id}doc334,doc125,doc777,doc321,doc253_ , will reach the query length limit if docIds are huge. Is there any other way to implement this in Solr, the way is has been done in ES.

Comment: There is no limit in Solr. Since you do this request server-side against Solr, there should be no limit in the GET request. If you encounter a limit, it is likely your servlet container (Jetty, Tomcat, Nginx) and consider raising the limit there.

Comment: Thanks, increasing the limit in Jetty worked for me. However, I still have to calculate the exclude list from SQL and then pass it on in a Solr query. Is there a way I can index my exclude list per customer on Solr itself, and filter it out at runtime for a given customer. One way I could think of is maintaining a separate core for keeping documents per customer and  excluded product_id perform a join using {!join} to filter out products for a customer. Is it a scalable solution.

Comment: Could you perhaps create a new question for this since this is another question.  So I can answer this and gain additional points. ;-)

Comment: Lol, sure. Please find the separate question here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46487646/how-to-filter-a-huge-list-of-ids-from-solr-at-runtime

Answer (score 1):

Use "ids" query:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-ids-query.html

```
{
    "query": {
        "ids" : {
            "type" : "my_type",
            "values" : ["1", "4", "100"]
        }
    }
}
```

Wrapped inside a bool > must_not.

Answer (score 0):

Add [Terms](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-terms-query.html) under [must_not](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html) section like the following:

```
{
  "must_not": [
    {
      "terms": {
        "id": [
          "1",
          "3",
          "5"
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```